# Do I need to override Rails and add "class" to has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Some of my has_many relations point to classes that have valid english names such as:

```
  has_many :users
  has_many :providers
```

but for some of them the model name is for example **key_perform_ind** so `has_many` will look like this:

```
has_many :key_perform_inds
```

So my question is should I in this case use the class keyword and explicitly tell rails what is the class I am talking about?

I am using Rails 3.2 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your association whatever you want... If the name differs from the actual class name, you'll need to specify it.

```
has_many :key_performing_industries, class_name: 'KeyPerformInd'
```